# $cov(X,f(X))\neq 0$ and $E(X f(X))\neq 0$

Tags: expected-value, covariance, independence

Take a random variable $X$. Is it true that

(1) $cov(X,f(X))\neq 0$ for any function $f$?

(2) $E(X f(X))\neq 0$ for any function $f$?

I believe the answer to both questions is no. However, can you suggest an $f$ such that $cov(X,f(X))= 0$ and an $f$ such that $E(X f(X))=0$? Let's exclude the constant functions $f(X)=k$.

Comment: consider f(x) = 0

Comment: Let's exclude the constant functions, sorry.

Comment: Fair, what about piecewise constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that these conditions need to be satisfied. For instance, assume that $f(X)=X^2$, and that $X$ has a symmetric distribution around 0, then:
$$
Cov(X,X^2)=E(X^3)-E(X)E(X^2)=0
$$
Since $E(X^k)=0$ for every odd $k$, as long as the moment exists.
I am pretty sure that you can come up with many more counterexamples.

Comment: To be more precise, we should say that $X$ is symmetrical around 0.

Comment: Good comment, I will edit my answer.